# How to get play and stop event callback from chromecast android

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, chromecast

I want to get callback event and perform some function when chromecast audio change there playback mode(play/stop)

How can I get the play/stop event to the application so I will do my work on that event.

Please check below logic I have implemented.

```
 private void setupCastListener() {
        mSessionManagerListener = new SessionManagerListener<CastSession>() {

            @Override
            public void onSessionEnded(CastSession session, int error) {
                onApplicationDisconnected();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionResumed(CastSession session, boolean wasSuspended) {
                onApplicationConnected(session);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionResumeFailed(CastSession session, int error) {
                onApplicationDisconnected();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionStarted(CastSession session, String sessionId) {
                onApplicationConnected(session);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionStartFailed(CastSession session, int error) {
                onApplicationDisconnected();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionStarting(CastSession session) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionEnding(CastSession session) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionResuming(CastSession session, String sessionId) {

                if(mCastSession!=null && isChromeCastConnected){
                  try {
                      if (session.isMute()) {
                          mStopPlayButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                          isChromeCastPlay = false;
                          //mCastSession.setMute(!mCastSession.isMute());
                      } else {
                          mStopPlayButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_stop);
                          isChromeCastPlay = true;
                          //mCastSession.setMute(!mCastSession.isMute());
                      }
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionSuspended(CastSession session, int reason) {
            }
        };
    }
```

Please let me know. thanks

Comment: Not a Chrome Apps question.

Comment: Find the relevant solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645972/chromecast-sdk-android-is-there-a-way-to-check-whether-the-media-playing-on/48852727#48852727

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the remote media play and pause mode call back by below MediaControlIntent.

> [Remote Playback Routes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/media/MediaControlIntent.html)

```
mMediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(this);
mSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
            .addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_REMOTE_PLAYBACK)
            .build();
```

Comment: Hey can you please share the code. I'm not getting where to put these.

Answer (score 4):

You need to read this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_integrate#how_media_control_works), and focus on [RemoteMediaClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/media/RemoteMediaClient) and the [Listener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/media/RemoteMediaClient.Listener) interface there. The callback onStatusUpdated() will be called when there is a change in the playback status. Tutorials available on the first link above is very informative, so make sure you read about things there.

Comment: Thank you for answer. can you please give me details about which eventcallback method I will use. because I have try all documention methods but fail not get play / stop event.

Comment: I had already mentioned even the name of the callback. Checkout https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android/blob/master/src/com/google/sample/cast/refplayer/mediaplayer/LocalPlayerActivity.java#L339

Comment: As per your answer and message I have implemented everything but still not get chromecast play/stop button event (call back listener) in sender app. please help me. thanks in advance

Comment: Did you look at the sample app that I mentioned to see how it is done there?